# Behaviour of Create Views in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-class-based-views

I am a newbie in Django pretty much. Since I want to step my game up now, I want to dive into ***generic class based views***. I already figured out how to use template views, but now I want to go for the create views.

I have these forms:

```
class LearningObjectiveForm(ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    exclude = ['trainee']
```

These models:

```
class LearningObjective(models.Model):
  trainee = models.ForeignKey(Trainee, blank = True)
  learning_objective = models.TextField()

class Trainee(models.Model):
  username = models.TextField()
  ...

class Topic(models.Model):
  trainee = models.ForeignKey(Trainee, blank = True)
  learning_objective = models.ManyToManyField(LearningObjective, blank = True, null = True)
  topic = models.TextField()
```

And this create view:

```
class CreateLearningObjective(CreateView):
  model = LearningObjective
  form = LearningObjectiveForm

  def form_valid(self, form):
    self.object = form.save(commit=False)
    if self.request.user.is_authenticated():
      self.object.trainee = self.request.user
    self.object.save()
    return super(CreateLearningObjective, self).form_valid(form)
```

My urls:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from programm import views

from .views import LearningObjectiveView, CreateLearningObjective

urlpatterns = patterns('',
  url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
  url(r'^learning_objective/$', LearningObjectiveView.as_view(), name = 'learning_objective'),
  url(r'^learning_objective_add/$', CreateLearningObjective.as_view(), name = 'learning_objective_add'),
)
```

Template:

```
<form action="{% url 'learning_objective_add' %}" method="post">
 {% csrf_token %}

 <textarea name="learning_objective" rows="4"></textarea>

 <p><select name="topic" size="6" multiple>
  {% for lO in learning_objectives %}
    {% for t in lO.topic_set.all %}
     <option>{{ t.topic }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
 </select></p>
<input type="submit" value="Absenden"/>
</form>
```

unfortunately when I try to submit a post, I just receive a `Cannot assign None: "LearningObjective.trainee" does not allow null values.` Error. Can anybody please help me?? I am really stuck and clueless what I should do right here :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your urls.py to:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
  url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
  url(r'^learning_objective/$', LearningObjectiveView.as_view(), name = 'learning_objective'),
  url(r'^learning_objective_add/$', CreateLearningObjective.as_view(), name = 'learning_objective_add'),
)
```

The error is that your second url ('^learning_objective') intercepts the post request to the third url.  This is why you should add `$` at the end of regex.

And `/` slash is also required for `POST` views because of `APPEND_SLASH` setting.

Comment: Can you show the whole content of urls.py and you form template?

Comment: You are not logged in, so `self.object.trainee` is not assigned in the `form_valid()`.

Comment: Sorry for misleading.  You souldn't call `return super(CreateLearningObjective, self).form_valid(form)` - it saves model again and, of course, it don't set `trainee` field.  Change this line to `return redirect(self.get_success_url())`.

Comment: Read the full stack trace and find the line in your code.